# How does RestKit map a out key to a model?

Tags: restkit

This is my json and managed object model:

```
{
    lasttime: 1387351751288
    AreaList: [
        {
            provinceid: 1,
            provincename: "a",
            count: 1,
        },
        {
            provinceid: 2,
            provincename: "b",
            count: 2,
        }
    ]
}

@interface Province : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * provinceid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * provincename;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * count;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * lasttime;

@end
```

I want to map the "lasttime" into the Province.lasttime, how should I modify the mapping?

Comment: it's hard to answer a question: "how should I modify mapping" without seeing mapping.

Comment: what I mean is that, if I can custom the mapping which corresponds to the Province to fit the need that map the outer lasttime into the lasttime in the province entity

Answer (score 0):

To copy direct into the object can not be done during the mapping because you can't both index into the array and use things outside the array at the same time.

I would consider mapping the time into its own object and then connect via a relationship with the provinces. Again, this can't be done entirely in the mapping for the same reason, so you would need to connect the objects in the success block.

Using the success block to make the connection would work just as well without the relationship if you map the time into an object and then copy the value across.

Comment: thanks Wain, last night I did it in the similar way, I create a new object model called AreaInfo which record the lasttime, and make a relationship to the province.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
    @"@parent.lasttime" : @"lasttime"
}];
```

Comment: This will only work with a response descriptor with a nil keypath, which I assume the OP doesn't have (otherwise the container that is mapped could hold the time and the province objects).